# com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Tags: java, spring, ssl, apple-push-notifications

i have a question related to APNS libary using spring framework.

What i'm trying to do is send push notification to an specific device if it has a pending message in database, i'm using a development certificate that is already proved to be valid, Here is my code block that is throwing an exception

```
ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
                                .withCert(messageDevice.getMessage().getMessageWebappCert(),"superDificultPasswordYouWillNeverGuessIn1Life")
                                .withProductionDestination()
                                .build();
service.testConnection();
```

and that's my problem because my code is throwing this SSL exception:

### com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

```
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.wrapAndThrowAsRuntimeException(Utilities.java:277)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:257)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:230)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.testConnection(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:294)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.testConnection(ApnsServiceImpl.java:57)
at com.ehecatl.noordwijk.util.MessageTask.sendMessagesSubject(MessageTask.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:240)
... 17 more
```

I really hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought it was certificate problem but the issue comes from the way I'm using the Dependency. What I need to do is check my pom.xml file and check the apns dependency. It must appear like in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ncpu.png). If it is not, it can be changed inside properties window, in Scope combobox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnSBZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the exact same issue when sending production notifications.
Turns out I was using a **certificate I revoked** a little while ago.

I changed to the new certificate and it works now.

Apple aborted the SSL handshake since it didn't recognize the client certificate I was using.

Comment: thanks, i though it wass my issue at first but the problem continued, now is fixed, the problem was the way I was using my Dependency